# What is the meaning of .end()->first in maps

Tags: c++, stl

Considering this piece of c++ code. Why is the output of mp.end()->first the number of keys in the container.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    map<int, char> mp;
    mp[0]='a';
    mp[1]='b';
    mp[2]='c';
    mp[3]='d';
    mp[3]='e';
    mp[7]='f';

    map<int, char>::iterator itr = mp.end();
    cout << itr->first << endl;


    return 0;       
}
```

The output for this code is **5**.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land, where any result you get is "correct".

Comment: Reminder:  assignment to a pointer or iterator is a valid operation.  The **dereferencing** operation may produce *Undefined Behavior* depending on the validity of the pointer or iterator's contents (or whether the pointer or iterator is pointing to a valid location).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best answer is going to come from the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end)

[image]

The `end()` function returns an iterator past the end of the map. Dereferencing it is undefined, so whatever output you see from this code is irrelevant.

What you probably want to do instead is look at `end() - 1`, in which case the result will be a `std::pair` of `int` and `char` giving you the key and value at that point in the map respectively (via members `first` and `second`). Have a look at [that reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) too.

Try this instead:

```
cout << (--itr)->first << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

as `Jon Reeves` said using an `iterator` and setting it to the `map`'s `end()` for later dereferencing is undefined behavior and will bring you garbage. An also correct way to achieve what you want is the following:

```
map<int, char>::reverse_iterator itr = mp.rbegin();
cout << (*itr).first << endl;
```

This will return `7`. If you want the letter or `value` use `(*itr).second` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but setting an iterator to `std::map::end()` is not undefined behavior, in fact the behavior is very well defined.  **Dereferencing** that iterator is undefined behavior.  In pointer and iterator land, there is a big difference between assignment and dereferencing.  A pointer or iterator can point to anywhere, including invalid locations.

Comment: For example, I use `const iterator end_iter = mp.end();` and it is not undefined behavior.  Usually, the pattern is:  `for (iterator iter = mp.begin(); iter != end_iter; ++iter)`.

Comment: That's true, Thomas. I wasn't specific enough, corrected it.

Comment: Thanks @CaioGuimarães